# Adding a fragment in android on button click and adding data to it simultaneously

Tags: android

I am creating a android app in which I have a main activity which has 2 fragments, fragUp and fragDown. fragUp has two edit text fields and a button and fragDown has two text view fields. 
Initially main activity shows only fragUp and asks user for the input fields, when the user clicks the button then onClick method is triggered and fragDown is created below fragUp and shows the two fields entered by the user.
 
Summary-
FRAGMENTS- fragUp , fragDown
MAIN ACTIVITY- main activity
Main activity has two linear layouts 
1.ly1 for fragUp
2.ly2 for fragDown

 
Note- All fragments are added dynamically in main java file and not declared in main.xml file.

This is main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragUp.fragInterface {
FragmentTransaction ft,ft1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
         ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragUp fu=new fragUp();

        ft.add(R.id.ly1,fu);          //Fragment fragUp is added dynamically.

    ft.commit();
        }

    public void set(String a,String b){

         ft1=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragDown ob=new fragDown();
        ft1.add(R.id.ly2,ob);
        ft1.commit();
        fragDown fd=(fragDown)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ly2);
        fd.seta(a, b);


    }
```

This is my fragUp java code-

```
public class fragUp extends Fragment {
    View v;
    public interface fragInterface{
        public void set(String a,String b);
    }
    fragInterface ob;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragup,container,false);
    Button b=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){ 
public void onClick(View v){ 
store();   
}});

    return v;
    }


    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        ob=(fragInterface)activity;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException();

    }
    }

     public void store(){           with main activity
    EditText et1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText et2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ob.set(et1.getText().toString(),et2.getText().toString());   //Interface implemented to share data 
}
}
```

This is fragDown java code-

```
public class fragDown extends Fragment {
View v;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragdown,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    public void seta(String a,String b){
        TextView t1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView t2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t1.setText(a);
        t2.setText(b);

    }
}
```

When I run the app and press the button my app crashes and logcat says-

```
08-05 09:37:02.198: E/AndroidRuntime(2866): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.fragment.fragDown.seta(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-05 09:37:02.198: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.example.fragment.Second.set(Second.java:30)
08-05 09:37:02.198: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.example.fragment.fragUp.store(fragUp.java:52)
08-05 09:37:02.198: E/AndroidRuntime(2866):     at com.example.fragment.fragUp$1.onClick(fragUp.java:25)
```

If anyone can help me then it would be great. I spent hours debugging it can't find where I went wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pass the values to the fragment as arguments? Check the "Layout" section on this guide: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Here's an excerpt from that guide that could help you:

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

Then when setting up the fragment:

```
// Prepare args
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putString(key, value);

// Init fragment and pass args
fragment = new DetailsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);

// Commit to the fragment manager, thus
// inflating the view
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.your_id, fragment).commit();
```

You can access the bundled arguments on your fragment's `onCreate` method.

Addressing your code specifically, you should:

- `MainActivity.set`, pass the args to your fragment:

  ```
  public void set(String a,String b) {
      ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragDown ob = new fragDown();

      // Add args. It is a good practice
      // to declare keys as public static final
      // variables, accessing them accordingly. Here
      // I'm just putting the string, but you should
      // avoid that.
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("key_a", a);
      args.putString("key_b", b);
      ob.setArguments(args);

      ft1.add(R.id.ly2, ob);
      ft1.commit();
  }
  ```
- Add `FragDown.onCreate` method:

  ```
  private String a = "";
  private String b = "";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      this.a = getArguments().getString("key_a");
      this.b = getArguments().getString("key_b");
  }
  ```
- Call `seta` on your `onCreateView`:

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragdown, container, false);
      seta(this.a, this.b)
      return v;
  }
  ```

this is due to the Fragment's lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Now, a bit of advice:

1. If you're serious about Android development, go read the links I posted (from top to bottom) until you understand them. Sorry, there's no way around them.
2. The "show me the code" kind of questions are usually considered rude and are prone to get downvoted or get hateful comments. StackOverflow is working towards a "be nice" campaign, and that's one of the main reasons I coped with it and followed up.
3. Asking a question in StackOverflow should really be your last resource, after you've exhausted every other option and have gone through docs, tutorials, source code, GitHub issues and Pull Requests, and so on.
4. Take this advice with a grain of salt :)

Comment: But I also need to inflate the fragment same time how will it be possible using arguments ?

Comment: Thanx for your reply but I am a beginner in android and this code seems quite unfamiler to me. So can you please tell me what changes should I do in my code :) .

Comment: It Worked !!!. Dude you are a pro :) . Thankyou so much for your help. And I will take care on all those points and read your links thoroughly.

Comment: and just one thing. After pressing the button I get the fragDown fragment as expected but if I change the data and press the button again then there is no change in fragDown fragment !!!